# Nuget update with PackageReference package management format

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I'm using the PackageReference package management format available in VS2017 rather than packages.config.

The Nuget restore command works fine, however, the Nuget update seems to be searching from projects that have a packages.config even though I'm explicitly providing the .sln file

The command I'm using is

\NuGet\4.0.0\x64\nuget.exe update "Test.sln"

The output I get is

`Scanning for projects...
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.3.409.57025' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.
Found 0 projects with a packages.config file.`

Does anyone know if this should work or some other way of forcing my packages to update?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if this should work or some other way of forcing my packages to update?

At the moment, NuGet CLI does not support automatic package updates to the the new .NET Core .csproj format, you can refer to the below GitHub issue for detail:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4358

If you want to force your packages to update, you can use the command line:

```
 dotnet add package PackageName --version <version>
```

to update the package to the version that you specify. See the [Github issue 4361](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4361) for detail.

**Update to the Comment**:
If you want to update to the latest version (without having to specify a specific version) of your nuget packages, you could use above command line **without** the option "`--version`":

```
dotnet add package PackageName
```

Besides, you can also use the command line `update-package` from the package manager console to update the package.

Comment: Hey Leo thanks for the response. Unfortunately I can't use update-package as I'm trying to update to the latest version (without having to specify a specific version) of my nuget packages as part of a TFS 2017 Update 2 build step. What would be the recommend approach for this?

Comment: @PatrickNolan, I see. You can use above the command line without the option "--Version", please check the update in my answer for detail. Hope helps.

Comment: Thanks @Leo-MSFT the problem is I don't want to set a specific version via --Version. I need to force Nuget to load the LATEST package. Any thoughts?

Comment: @PatrickNolan, you should really double check my update answer. You could use the command line `dotnet add package PackageName` WITHOUT the option --version.

Comment: Hey @Leo-MSFT I'm not doubting it would probably work, I just want to confirm there isn't a better solution. This requires that I explicitly update each package. As a result if a package dependency is added to a project by a developer, the build process has to also be updated to explicitly call an update operation for that package. Ideally, there would be the ability to update all packages for a project based on a feed like you can do currently for the Restore operation.

Comment: @PatrickNolan, I see. Unfortunately, NuGet CLI does not support new .NET Core .csproj format. And there is no dotnet restore update or dotnet nuget update option available. So, at the moment, it is impossible to update all packages for PackageReference package management format.

Comment: @PatrickNolan to automatically update packages to the latest version available on the feed use a floating version. Example: Version="1.*" Running nuget.exe restore with -Force will resolve the latest version of the package, the result is the same as if you updated the PackageReference to the latest available version before building.